# Problems reading excel file with PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am having trouble reading a file with PHPExcel. Here is the error I'm getting:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_Cell' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TestRailIntegration/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php on line 739
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0023  649920  {main}( )   ../testRailScripting.php:0
2   0.0030  755712  PHPExcel_IOFactory::load( ) ../testRailScripting.php:23
3   0.0038  797288  PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007->load( )  ../IOFactory.php:193
```

And here is my code:

```
<?php 
include './Classes/PHPExcel.php';

echo 'Hello world' . "\n";
$FileName = $_FILES["fileName"]["name"];

$inputFileName=$_FILES["fileName"]["tmp_name"];
echo $inputFileName;

if(file_exists("uploadedFiles/".$_FILES["fileName"]["name"])){
    echo $_FILES["fileName"]["name"]." already exists";
}
else{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileName"]["tmp_name"],"uploadedFiles/".$_FILES["fileName"]["name"]);
    echo $_FILES["fileName"]["name"]." has been moved";
}

$PHPExcelObj = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you moved the file to "uploadedFiles" folder so:

```
$PHPExcelObj = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("uploadedFiles/".$inputFileName);
```